# How to add rendezvous point in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a scenario in which I want to hit first request with 3000 users and wait for all the users to come at a point and hit the second request at a same time.
How can this be achievable in jmeter.

Answer (score 4):

JMeter's equivalent of rendezvous point is [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer). Add it as a child of the request you need to execute by all users and use `3000` as the "Number of Simulated Users to Group By"

[image: JMeter Synchronizing Timer]

Answer (score 1):

You could write the first request in its own ThreadGroup wich loops 3000 times, then the 2nd request in an other ThreadGroup.

If you tick the `Run Test Group consecutively` check-box on the [Test Plan configuration screen](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan):

[image: Tick the 1st Checkbox]

Then what you ask will happen.

You'll have to pass the user states somehow, maybe using variables?

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you could have a global variable `user_setup_count` and an absolute `rendez_vous_time`, to be used like this (for each `Thread`, in a `single` ThreadGroup):

- **Perform request1**
- Increment `user_setup_count` - Set `rendez_vous_time` to `now + 20s`
- `while (user_setup_count <3000) {` Not everyone is ready yet!

  - Sleep for 5 sec
- Sleep *exactly* until `rendez_vous_time` <-- Synchronization is here
- **Perform request 2**
- etc.